# Postgres column does not exist in function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

In my query I am getting error message as below:

> ERROR:  column "pw" does not exist
>
> LINE 1: SELECT  (pw = $2)  FROM    user
> ^ QUERY:  SELECT  (pw = $2)                     FROM    user
> WHERE   user_name = $1
>
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function public.check_password(text,text) line 4 at
> SQL statement

SQL state: 42703

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_password(i VARCHAR, pwd VARCHAR)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
DECLARE passed Boolean;
    BEGIN
    
        SELECT (u.pw = pwd) into passed
        From public.user u
        where u.user_name = i;
        return passed;
        
    END;
    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select check_password('userf','12345');
```

[image]

Comment: Is it supposed to be `u.pwd`? If not add to your question the table definition for `public.user`.

Comment: `user` is a reserved keyword. Try `public."user"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function works, but You may need consider the **null** case.
[**demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a92163b5df81ef947bb7b9a1d2c82112)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_password(i text, pwd text)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
DECLARE passed Boolean;
    BEGIN
    
        SELECT (u.pw = pwd) into passed
        From public.user u
        where u.user_name = i;
        
        if passed is null then  passed := false; end if;
        
        return passed;
        
    END;
    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Or simpler: `return passed is true`